# Как изменить цвет кнопки в popup при наведении мыши?

Tags: c#, wpf

Здравствуйте.

Есть Popup в нем есть кнопки - как изменить цвет кнопки в popup при наведении мыши?

```
<Popup x:Name="popup" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=btn}">
    <Border>
        <StackPanel>
            <Button>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Margin="2" VerticalAlignment="Center">Текст 1</TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>
            <Button>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Margin="2" VerticalAlignment="Center">Текст 2</TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>
            <Button>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Margin="2" VerticalAlignment="Center">Текст 3</TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</Popup>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
```

Comment: Это не тот эффект, который нужен. Цвет меняется только у кнопки, а в popup - нет. Нужно что-то типа свойства `IsHighlighted`, как в `MenuItem`, но только у `Button` задать. Как это можно сделать?